# How can I redirect traffic staging site without combining the domain prefix and suffix?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've got a question about apache configs or it may be the .httaccess file. I have staging site : staging.witnesstolove.org with https enabled. when I try to go to the site, I'm redirected to stagingwitnesstolove.org and I'm not sure why?

My apache config seems pretty basic:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin accounts@1905newmedia.com
     DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/staging/witnesstolove/current/site/web/
     ServerName staging.witnesstolove.org


     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     <Directory /home/ubuntu/staging/witnesstolove/current/site/web/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =staging.witnesstolove.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I see in devtools that i'm getting a 301 redirect and it says it's being redirected by wordpress.

If I look at the .htaccess file for the site, it's like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Based on the response headers I'm getting back, it sounds like wordpress is redirecting the traffic to the other domain?

Here's the HTTPS config for the site in Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin accounts@1905newmedia.com
     DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/staging/witnesstolove/current/site/web/
     ServerName staging.witnesstolove.org


     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     <Directory /home/ubuntu/staging/witnesstolove/current/site/web/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =staging.witnesstolove.org
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.witnesstolove.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.witnesstolove.org/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Like you say, this would seem to something that needs resolving in WordPress itself. There's nothing "wrong" with the Apache config/.htaccess you've posted. Is it an issue with the HTTP to HTTPS redirect (you've only posted the HTTP config)? Or is it attempting to canonicalise the requested hostname?

Comment: @MrWhite That's a good question. I added the https config file for the site. I checked wp-options and it shows staging.witnesstolove.org in the domain settings.